# Why is Solidify modifier producing results I did not expect?

Tags: modifiers

Solidify modifier is not working the way I expected. I have a simple extruded mesh and I want to give it a solid thickness with Solidify modifier. When the modifier is added it does not produce a perfect even mesh at the edges.

[image]

[image]

How can I give a solid thickness to my mesh?

Comment: Firstly, when you have sides that move outwards, they will not align well. Secondly, The solidify tool is not made to fill in thick walls perfectly. it is mostly used for adding thickness to glass and other thin sheets. I recommend using the extrude tool and manually moving different faces around. What I did was extruded the whole wall away from the main face. I then grabbed any overhangs and pulled them upwards/downwards as required.

Comment: as said by Bigfoot, when you try a negative value, it will work better. Also try to enable the Even Thickness and High Quality Normals options. And if it's still not good, as said by Bigfoot, give thickness with extrusions and work with the vertices